# How to get the index of a JMenuItem in the JMenu?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

I need to find the index of a specific `JMenuItem` in a `JMenu` so I can programatically `insert()` a new `JMenuItem` right before it. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: Have you tried Container#getComponentZOrder(Component)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer guess you forgot adding link, here it is: [Container#getComponentZOrder(Component)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component%29)

Comment: @Frakcool Nah, I'm on the iPad and it's just a pain...:P

Comment: @MadProgrammer Make it an answer if you want :) BTW: is there a reason people write `Class#method` instead of `Class.method`? Is it some kind of convention?

Comment: I use Class#method to indicate a instance method! where as Class.method indicates a static method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Container#getComponentZOrder(Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponentZOrder(java.awt.Component)) which should return the index position of the component within the container

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code sample of the same solution as suggested above:

```
JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
popup.setName("popup");
JMenu jMenu= new JMenu("menu");
jMenu.setName("menu");
JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("sub1");
jMenu.add(menuItem1);
menuItem1.addActionListener(this);
popup.add(jMenu);
```

....

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JMenuItem source = (JMenuItem)(e.getSource());
    try{
        JMenuItem menuItem = (JMenuItem) e.getSource(); 
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = (JPopupMenu) menuItem.getParent(); 
        Component invoker = popupMenu.getInvoker();  
        // Print MenuItem index against the total number of items
        System.out.println(popupMenu.getComponentZOrder(menuItem)+"/"+popupMenu.getComponentCount());
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JMenuItem action listener, get the source and do something like this..

```
for(int i = 0; i < jmenu.getMenuComponents().length; i++){
     if(jMenu.getMenuComponent(i) == jMenuItem ){
              // so that i is index here...
     }
}
```

here `jMenuItem is e.getSource()`